# Is it possible to reduce the size of Outlook 365 email response buttons?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

The `Reply`, `Reply All`, and `Forward` buttons in the "new" (to me as of Jan 27, 2019) Outlook feel very large and distracting to me.  I tend to use keyboard shortcuts for response actions, such as `alt` + `r`, anyway.  Is it possible to reduce the buttons' size or remove them from the message header?

Maybe I'm simply forgetting they were already this size because this 2014 question about the same or [similar concern in Outlook 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/698369/annoying-reply-reply-all-forward-buttons-in-outlook-2013) was answered that there was no way to change it.  I've failed to see anything within the past year in Google results that answers this question.  Thanks.

[URL/announcement with the following image](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-blog/outlook-for-windows-rolls-out-its-simplified-user-experience/ba-p/653734).

[image: snippet of large buttons from Microsoft post]

Answer (score 3):

No, button size cannot be changed within Outlook. I had the Office Ribbon get too large (DISM fix) and discovered during this research that the button and ribbon sizes cannot be changed inside Office applications.

These sizes are affected by Screen Resolution and Scale (Modern Windows 10 versions)